# Is there a word that encompasses both collaboration and individual help/assistance

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm making a web widget that will include social media functionality (Twitter, Facebook, etc..) and also a personal chat with sales.  I'm looking for a word (idea, concept, jargon) or some kind of universal image/icon that unambiguously communicates this succinctly.  Sorry, if this seems lame.

Comment: What is wrong with help or assistance?

Comment: Help/Assistance is good for the second concept, but it doesn't imply any kind of Collaboration/SocialMedia

Comment: So you want a word that means collaborative via social media *and* one-on-one interaction?

Comment: yeah, more or less

Answer (score 1):

Why not create your own portmanteau word such as helperate/helperation or assisterate/assisteration, to me these seem cumbersome however.

An alternative would be to use AID, but this is a word with unwanted connotations, and may have a negative impact on your advertising.

A possible alternative would be assist.

If you're looking at the social mediaspect as a necessary part of the connotation then something along the lines of co-bridge, chain-bridge co-link, or even simply "Clink" or "Klink".

Another possible alternative may be to use a giff as an image file instead of pure text, you could then scroll or cross-fade, like a mini slide-show these words and any alternatives you can think of in turn. an image of three interlocking chain links might be what appeals most in this case, pyramidal or tetrahedra, maybe, but the idea of a picture with a link missing - inviting your customer to join at that point may be just the thing. Klink! (I hope this last answer is not considered off-topic)

Comment: Individuals don't get to legislate on wordness.